# Plotting Uniform and Non-Uniform Binary Search Tree Graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I need to create two binary search tree graphs, showing the branches of a radix-2 and radix < 2 binary search methods. I want to graphically show the code redundancy employed in successive approximation A/D converters which use binary weight of < 2. Ideally a golden radio radix would also be suitable (1.618).

For that purpose I have decided to use the python igraph library and have discovered the Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed functions e.g.:

```
from igraph import *;

pl=Plot();

g = Graph.Tree(16, 2);
layout = g.layout("rt", 1); # Reingold-Tilford tree layout, useful for (almost) tree-like graphs

pl.add(g, layout=layout);
pl._windows_hacks=True;
pl.show();
```

Unfortunately, this generates a tree whose branches are not binary i.e. I get three nodes right after the root node. I also need a balanced tree, which this function does not seem to provide (tree branches are unbalanced):

[image: You can find the obtained tree here]

I came along the Bipartite class method in the igraph library, but I am not sure if I am in the right path at all.

I would be glad if someone more experienced with igraph and tree visualizations could give me a hand on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this plot. I solved it by specifying the root for the layout like this:

```
layout = g.layout("rt", root=(0,0))
```